# Click a link > go to Contact Page > make a checkbox checked

Tags: checkbox

I'm having a link "Request a call" in the header which goes to the Contact Page. 
If clicked it should go to the Page (as it does), where there is a Form and a Checkbox ("Requtest a call")  > that should be checked
(only if you come from that certain link)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BOOL variable's property in contact view controller. Set that variable true while pushing in case of navigation from link("Request a call"). Set checked/unchecked value in checkbox from bool variable.